# How can other time lords, post time-war, drive/fly a TARDIS?

Tags: doctor-who, tardis

Two parts allow time lords to fly through time and space, in TARDII (?):

1. When a Gallifreyan was granted the rank of Junior Time Lord in the Time Lord Academy, they received their **symbiotic nuclei**. (PROSE: Interference - Book One)
2. The Sixth Doctor once claimed that TARDISes (or other time machines) had to be primed with a Rassilon Imprimatur to enabled them to travel safely in time.(TV: The Two Doctors)

<sub>~[Rassilon Imprimatur](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Rassilon_Imprimatur)</sub>

Now, no one is making more TARDISes, but we've seen a few new time-lords...in the loosest sense:

> 1. [Donna-Doctor](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Journey%27s_End)
>  2. [The Doctors Clone/Daughter](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Doctor%27s_Daughter_%28TV_story%29)
>  3. [River Song](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Let%27s_Kill_Hitler_%28TV_story%29)

Now, we haven't seen all of these fly the TARDIS, we've do it with the Doctor, but that's cheating.

Do these/would/should these have the same ability to fly the TARDIS? If not, what's the limitation on flying one without the symbiotic nuclei? Has anyone managed that?

Comment: Axis Axes, Tardis Tardes?

Comment: @Nick It's an acronym, so I was only playing when I said TARDII...

Comment: +1 for actually using the word TARDII.

Comment: 4 - Ashildr aka "Me" flying a TARDIS, though not a timelord/gallifreyan

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have only actually seen *one* person fly a TARDIS, on their own, without The Doctor being involved, and that's River Song. (Donna flew it in conjunction with The Clone Doctor, I think.)

In general your intuition seems to be correct that we shouldn't be seeing anyone else new being able to pilot the TARDIS. Eleven seems stunned when River demonstrates an aptitude for piloting his TARDIS, and claims it ought to be impossible. In River's case, she explains in *Let's Kill Hitler* how she was able to do it - the TARDIS let her. When she pilots the TARDIS to where The Doctor is dying of poison, she explains to everyone that "she [the TARDIS] taught me how to fly her."

In general, in the post Time-War era, the individuality and personality of the TARDIS has been something brought much more to the forefront. Remember she is the last TARDIS as much as he is the last Doctor. It seems as if the "rules" surrounding TARDIS flight in the age of the Time Lords are only conventions or guidelines that everyone followed, and not anything that is inherent to the nature of a TARDIS.

So, in theory, a TARDIS *could* permit anyone they wanted to fly them, and teach them how, but so far, of all the people that have been in the TARDIS post-Time War, only one (a very unique one) has actually been able to do so.

Comment: So you might speculate that no one else could?

Comment: @Pureferret more like, anyone else will have to follow River's path and have to be taught directly by the TARDIS.

Comment: The Master was also able to pilot the Doctor's TARDIS in "Utopia": http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Utopia_(TV_story)

Comment: The Master is a true Time Lord; he would have the same capacity to pilot The Doctor's TARDIS as The Doctor himself (and has done so many times in the past). I assume if there are any other true Time Lords that managed to escape the time lock, they'd still be able to pilot a TARDIS as well.

Comment: Since you wrote this, we've also seen Tasha Lem fly the TARDIS in *The Time of the Doctor*.

Answer (score 1):

In the earlier ones Season 19 for example, there is  a companion "adric" who managed to fly the Tardis several times alone.

Comment: That's pre-Time War.

Comment: @Keen true, but there was nothing "special" about Adric that would allow him to pilot a TARDIS alone; if he and Nyssa could do it w/out a Time Lord assisting then in theory anyone should. I will note, however, that 1. The TARDIS became much easier to pilot during  the course of 4 and 5's tenure, and 2. Adric only piloted the TARDIS a short distance and only through space, which may be easier.

Answer (score 0):

We have seen in much earlier series both the Master and Rani fly a TARDIS.  I think Romana also bit in some episodes it  became clear the Romana and Rani where the same woman. Also went to school with the Doctor. She also helped the Doctor on occasion instead of the Master.

Comment: This answer is a. It unclear in places and could do with you [edit]ing in some evidence for the points you make as well to back it up!

Comment: Neither of these are post time war, are they?